# Why do I need to qualify local variables?

Tags: python

In this class:

```
class MyClass () :
    foo = 1

    @staticmethod
    def bar () :
        print MyClass.foo
```

Why do I need to qualify `foo` with `MyClass`? (otherwise I get `NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined`.

Isn't `foo` local to the class `MyClass`?

Answer (score 3):

This is because Python's scope lookup order is LEGB (locals, enclosed function, global, builtin). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/443348). Python has an explicit class variable, which is the first argument of the method, typically named `self`. Normally one would access `foo` by using `self.foo` But in this case, the function is a static method, so it does not receive an explicit class variable, so there is no alternative way to access `foo`. Either remove the reference to `foo` or remove the `@staticmethod` decorator from the `bar()`and add `self` as the first argument of `bar()`.

Comment: @sds You might want to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that because the bar function is a static method. This means you can call it without regarding an instance of the containing class. IE you don't have to create an instance of the class to access that function.

You can read more about it - [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Comment: Not entirely accurate. I mean, instance variables need to be qualified as well...

Answer (score 0):

This is called class attribute
which could be accessed directly by `MyClass.foo`, and owned by the class.
It's not owned by the instances of the class

for `self` this is instance variable, each instance of a class has a new copy of the variables

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the concept of "local variables" really fully exists only in functions. A function (method) inside a class does not have implicit access to the class's (or instance's) scope; you must explicitly specify the object containing the desired attribute, i.e., the class or the instance (by convention passed to the method as `self`). As to why it was designed that way... you'd have to ask Guido, but the Zen of Python says "explicit is better than implicit" so that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't foo local to the class MyClass?

Actually, no. It's local to the `class` statement's body, which the `bar` function cannot access. Once the class object created and bound to `MyClass`, `foo` becomes an attribute of the class object (just like `bar` FWIW), but that's namespace, not scope.

Also and FWIW, Python's `staticmethod` dont access the class itself. If you want a method that needs to access the class, use a `classmethod` instead.